# Remove key from map kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, dictionary

I have a map as follows

```
  val parentMap= mutableMapOf<String,String>()
    parentMap["key1"]="value1"
    parentMap["key2"]="value2"
    parentMap["key3"]="value3"
```

And I have a list of keys `val keyList= listOf("key1","key3")`

I want to remove the `key` from map which doesn't exist in my `keylist`

The current solution I am using is

```
val filteredMap= mutableMapOf<String,String>()
    keyList.forEach {
        if(parentMap.containsKey(it))
            filteredMap[it]=parentMap[it]!!
    }
    println(filteredMap)
```

Is there any more better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it much easier like this:

```
val filteredMap = parentMap.filter { keyList.contains(it.key) }
```

Comment: worth noting that depending on the size of the list, it might be better to first make it a set.

Comment: Or, equivalently, `parentMap.filter{ it.key in keyList }`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved even a little shorter:

```
val map = mapOf(
     "key1" to "value1",
     "key2" to "value2",
     "key3" to "value3"
)
 
val list = listOf("key1")
 
val filteredMap = map.filterKeys(list::contains)
```

the result is: `{key1=value1}`